# Update elements from json string java

Tags: java, json

i have following json string response received from the server.

```
{
   "entities":[
      {
         "Fields":[
            {
               "Name":"detection-version",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"subject",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"description",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"target-rcyc",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"project",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"changeset",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"has-linkage",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"N"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"last-modified",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"2016-05-31 18:38:54"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"has-others-linkage",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"N"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"attachment",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"cycle-id",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"request-type",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"build-detected",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"creation-time",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"2016-05-17"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"actual-fix-time",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"id",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"4"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"run-reference",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"request-note",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"request-server",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"severity",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"1-Low"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"to-mail",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"owner",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"detected-by",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"demouser02"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"build-closed",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"step-reference",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"estimated-fix-time",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"reproducible",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"ver-stamp",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"1"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"request-id",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"priority",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"cycle-reference",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"environment",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"target-rel",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"test-reference",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"planned-closing-ver",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"extended-reference",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"dev-comments",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"detected-in-rcyc",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"closing-version",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"name",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"test"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"has-change",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"user-01",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"has-changeset-link",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"N"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"detected-in-rel",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"status",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"closing-date",
               "values":[

               ]
            }
         ],
         "Type":"defect",
         "children-count":0
      },
      {
         "Fields":[
            {
               "Name":"detection-version",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"subject",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"description",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"target-rcyc",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"project",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"changeset",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"has-linkage",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"N"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"last-modified",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"2016-05-31 18:38:58"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"has-others-linkage",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"N"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"attachment",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"cycle-id",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"request-type",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"build-detected",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"creation-time",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"2016-05-17"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"actual-fix-time",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"id",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"5"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"run-reference",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"request-note",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"request-server",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"severity",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"1-Low"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"to-mail",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"owner",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"detected-by",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"demouser02"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"build-closed",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"step-reference",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"estimated-fix-time",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"reproducible",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"ver-stamp",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"1"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"request-id",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"priority",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"cycle-reference",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"environment",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"target-rel",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"test-reference",
               "values":[

               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"planned-closing-ver",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"extended-reference",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"dev-comments",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"detected-in-rcyc",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"closing-version",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"name",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"test"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"has-change",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"user-01",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"has-changeset-link",
               "values":[
                  {
                     "value":"N"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"detected-in-rel",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"status",
               "values":[
                  {

                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "Name":"closing-date",
               "values":[

               ]
            }
         ],
         "Type":"defect",
         "children-count":0
      }
   ],
   "TotalResults":920
}
```

i need to update the following values for all defects in this string

```
{
   "Name":"detected-by",
   "values":[
      {
         "value":"demouser02"
      }
   ]
}
```

i need to update detected by to "Reported by" and demouser02 to "Adwait"

Please help.

Comment: ever heard of json formatters/beautifiers my friend? 
http://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

Comment: Can you share some code sample that you have already implemented?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you mean, you can do somthing like this :

```
public class EntiteFile extends Serializable{

private List<Entite<Filed>> entites;
....

}

public class Entite<Filed> extends Serializable {


 private List<Filed> fileds;

}


public clas Value extends Serializable {

private String value;

....
}

public class Filed extends Serializable {

private String name;

private List<Value> values ;
.....
 }
```

and to read you're file you can use :

```
 EntiteFile entities = mapper.readValue(getJsonFile(nameFile), EntiteFile.class);

for(Entite entite : entities.getEntites ){
for(Field field : Fields ){
if("detected-by".equals(field.getName())){
field.setName("Reported by");
for(Value value : field.getValues){
value.setValue("Adwait");
}
}
}
}
```

...
...

Answer (score 0):

JSONSimple. AS Simple as it gets. Try it! https://www.mkyong.com/java/json-simple-example-read-and-write-json/